# Parsing variable length data

Tags: python, regex, string, parsing

I'm using Python 3 and Im relatively new to RegEx.
I'm struggling to come up with a good way to tackle the following problem.
I have a text string (that can include line breaks etc) that contains a several sets of information.

For example:

```
TAG1/123456 TAG2/ABCDEFG HISTAG3/A1B1C1D1 QWERTY TAG4/0987654321 
TAG5/THE CAT SAT ON THE MAT MYTAG6/FLINTSTONE 
TAG7/99887766AA
```

I need this parsed to the following

```
TAG1/123456

TAG2/ABCDEFG

HISTAG3/A1B1C1D1 QWERTY

TAG4/0987654321

TAG5/THE CAT SAT ON THE MAT

MYTAG6/FLINTSTONE

TAG7/99887766AA
```

I can't seem to work out how to deal with the variable length tags :( TAG3 and TAG5
I always end up capturing the next tag i.e.

```
TAG5/THE CAT SAT ON THE MAT TAG6
```

In reality the TAGs themselves are also variable. Most are 3 characters followed by '/' but not all. Some are 4, 5 and 6 characters long. But all are followed by '/' and all EXCEPT the first one are preceded by a space

**Updated Information**
*I have updated the example to show these variable tags. But to clarify a tag can be 1-8 alphabetic characters, preceded by a space and terminated by '/'
The data after the tag can be one or more words (alphanumeric) and is defined as all the data that follows the '/' of the tag up until the start of the next tag or the end of the string*.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I should probably also say that I'm after them one at a time. i.e. I just want to extract TAG5

Comment: "In reality the TAGs themselves are also variable" -- with such a vague specification, any suggestion we might make can be counteracted by a "does not work for me". Please provide as much information as possible -- including your (failed) attempts.

Comment: What's the state of the regex you have?

Comment: What i have tried that doesnt work.. .*?[ |-]TAG5/(?P<TAG5Tag>[0-9A-Z ]+(([0-9A-Z]+)?){10})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way to achieve what you want I think:

```
import re

s = """TAG1/123456 TAG2/ABCDEFG TAG3/A1B1C1D1 QWERTY TAG4/0987654321 
TAG5/THE CAT SAT ON THE MAT TAG6/FLINTSTONE 
TAG7/99887766AA"""
r = re.compile(r'\w+/.+?(?=$|\s+\w+/)')
tags = r.findall(s)
print(*tags, sep='\n')
```

Output:

```
TAG1/123456
TAG2/ABCDEFG
TAG3/A1B1C1D1 QWERTY
TAG4/0987654321
TAG5/THE CAT SAT ON THE MAT
TAG6/FLINTSTONE
TAG7/99887766AA
```

The important bits are the non-greedy qualifier `+?` and the lookahead `(?=$|\s+\w+/)`.

Comment: Doh! Thank you. That is what I was after. I was coming at it the wrong way. I had tried use a negative lookahead

Comment: Reference to non-greedy qualifiers is because qualifiers * and + (used like .* and .+) are called 'greedy' because (when unqualified) they match as much as they can. Qualifying with ? as in .*? and .+? makes them non-greedy - they match as  little as they can.